# postgres encoding and django-actstream

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm using django activity stream: https://github.com/justquick/django-activity-stream/

It seems to be working fine except that I created a follow-relationships for an object with the character é and the admin view now returns a 500 error:

'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)

On the console, when I query the record, I get:

What could be causing this and how can I prevent it?